# Can't find openssl.cnf file

Tags: ssl, openssl

I just cloned the git repository for openssl from git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git.
and im trying to find the openssl.cnf file but its nowhere to be found??

Where is this file located?

Comment: In `apps/`. Which originally was the only place it was used, although over the years some uses in library were added. PS: you could have found this yourself in less than a second with `find` on Unix or `dir /s` on Windows.

Comment: id did use dir... its not there i think something is wrong

Comment: Have a look for openssl.cfg.  Should be same file, just different extension.  I have even seen openssl.ini too.

Comment: I found it, it was .cfg extension i was looking for cnf.

Comment: That's interesting; it's .cnf in [the (claimed) github mirror](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/tree/master/apps) and (all) the release tarballs I have downloaded, but I don't use the direct repo.